# Android: Unwanted White Box at Top of Screen (toolbar?)

Tags: android, xml, layout, toolbar

How do I get rid of the white box at the top of the android view? I cannot see anywhere in my code where I called something that created the toolbar, nor did I code it myself. It also exists above the view, not in it. I'm guessing there is some setting in the design view of the xml file that can toggle it? Thanks in advance!

** I should also include that it is only on this activity, and my other activities do not have this white bar at the top. Furthermore, the actionbar is the thin blue bar above the white car, so any code that involves manipulating the actionbar will not change the white bar's status. **

### [image: Android View with weird toolbar]

EDIT: XML Code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bucket"
    android:theme="@+id/BucketTheme2"
    android:backgroundTint="#70FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_over">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="100dp"
            android:text="Find a place to go around you!"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="randomButtonPressed"
            android:text="RANDOMIZE"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bucketBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="bucketButtonPressed"
            android:text="Bucket List"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchLocationBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="searchButtonPressed"
            android:text="Search by Location"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2: style.xml code for BucketTheme2 is below (I did not post it initially because it only sets colors):

```
<style name="BucketTheme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: share your layout code

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: Remove `android:backgroundTint="#70FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"`

Comment: share your styles.xml also.

Comment: can you upload style.xml and which style you used as theme? i guess that is toolbar/appbar/primary color.

Comment: @Piyush that is there to made the background image tinted. It does not have to do with the white bar at the top

Comment: Are u extending `Activity / AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam yes I am extending `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: post your BucketTheme2 xml code

Comment: @NikhilSharma just posted it but as you can see it only sets colors.

Comment: @kiley just check my answer below it will work fine for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set theme for application or activity in Manifest.xml to remove action bar:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Or add the following code in Activity in the onCreate method and import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: the `getSupportActionBar( ).hide( )` code worked! Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: so for anyone else looking at this, I think whether or not the support action bar is there is determined by whether the class implements `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`. When I changed the class's implementation to `Activity`, the bar disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

**Add** the following theme to the `style.xml`

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

Then set this theme to the activity in `manifest`:

```
  <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

**UPDATE:** You can also set the theme as below:

```
<style name="BucketTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately the bar is still there :/ that just removed the statusbar at the top.

Comment: This should not remove the statusbar. Did you remove the code previously added ? Please share `BucketTheme2` code. If you made any modification to theme in activity class, show it too.

Comment: I included the BucketTheme2 code, but as you can see it only sets colors for the theme.

Answer (score 2):

Add NoActionBar style in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And add this theme to your activity from manifest,

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
    </activity>
```

Comment: unfortunately that only got rid of the statusbar at the top :/

Comment: @Kiley i have edited the snippet and its working for me ,check it out ,if it helps you pls vote for answer

Comment: thank you for the help but even with the edits I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Can u share your manifest.xml n style.xml and make sure you are not using toolbar in xml

Comment: The view sets it's personal theme to `BucketTheme2`, so the manifest code would not affect this. I posted `BucketTheme2`'s code from the `style.xml` file, and as you can see it only sets colors.

Comment: In your BucketTheme2 its showing DarkActionBar as parent instead of it you should use NoActionBar as parent,DarkActionBar Theme gives a window with an action bar,and NoActionBar theme gives a window without an action bar.

Comment: again thank you for the help but someone else has answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

Change your activity theme in manifest to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and you should be sorted

Comment: unfortunately, this made the action bar disappear but the white bar was still there :/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

it should be before setContentView

Comment: This will also diminish the statusbar.

Comment: then only use the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: this code actually got rid of the statusbar at the top, but the white bar was still there :/

Comment: try to run this code on the device, the title bar should be removed and the notification bar will be still there if you used the first line only. and if it is not the case then i need to see your style file

Answer (score 1):

Just try this in your style

```
<style name="BucketTheme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Comment: unfortunately the bar is still there :/ this just removed the statusbar at the top.

Comment: Can you also provide a screen shot with layout bounds enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue when using a template project that Android studio already set up. I noticed that in the activity_main.xml file there was unnecessary padding at the top once I changed to a theme of *.NoActionBar. If you remove android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" it should go away.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```